# Do we say "improvement in precision" or "improvement to precision"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> Engineers made several improvements in precision in recent years.

I think "in" sounds more natural, but I would also be inclined to use "to". Are both phrasing equivalent, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Engineers made several improvements in precision in recent years.

- make precision improvements
  OR
- to make improvements to precision: to make improvements to [something]
  OR
- to make improvements in automation or construction [field of study or field of activity]

precision is not a field of study, so it doesn't work here.